# What is Face of the Mountain's best strategic use?

Tags: league-of-legends

Against which champions does Face of the Mountain work the best? I've read some post that suggests making it when your team has an assassin, is this accurate?

Are there any other good uses for it?

Answer (score 1):

I would be more inclined to build this if you are AGAINST an assassin, and only if you are playing Alistar or Braum. Those champions have more health than the other squishier supports like Soraka or Sona.

The active can keep your ADC alive through an assassin attempt at their life.

Likewise to your point, you can also use it on YOUR assassin to give them the ability to wipe the enemy team and survive the engage.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should only get FoTM in cases where the enemy team is very likely to dive your carries (think Irelia, Hecarim, Leblanc vs immobile carries like KogMaw or Karthus) or has high burst damage - otherwise it's not gold efficient; you would benefit more from the usual Eye of the Equinox rush.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Buy it on every Melee/Tank supporter. Don't buy it on AP supporters. Never upgrade it to Eye of the Equinox or resell the shield.

Face of the mountain is a great Item on any Melee or Tanky support and a... well mostly average to bad item on anything that doesn't build tanky.

Let's look at the stats and the active:

- 450 Health
- 100% Base health regeneration
- 10% Cooldown reduction
- Killing a minion grants You and your nearest ally gold and heals both of you for 50 HP.
   4 charges
- (Active) Shield an ally for 10% Of your max HP. After 4 seconds the shield explodes and slows all nearby enemies by 40%.

Now pretty much all base stats on this item are extremely useful for any melee support but the most important things are the passive and the active of the item.

The passive heals you and a nearby ally by 50 health. If you use all 4 stacks that's **200 HP**. For reference: Heal at level 8 heals for 195 HP so if you get the item before lvl 9 the healing output from the passive alone is **higher than that of a summoner spell**.

And that's just the passive healing. The shield can even grow stronger and it's on a 60 second cooldown. 10% of your max health means that even in lategame you will have a strong shield. Especially on tanky supporters like Leona, Braum or Thresh I often find myself having more than 3.5K HP which means that you can potentially shield yourself or an ally for 350+ HP. That is an absolute crazy amount of bonus HP on demand for an item with great stats in general which only costs 2.2k gold.

Now to sum it up: Always buy this item on a tanky or melee support. Regardless of the enemy team comp. The stats, Healing and shield are just too good to not take it. This also includes Eye of the Equinox. The shield will be a lifesaver whereas wards can come from a ruby sightstone which provides decent stats aswell.

Now for utility supporters you should refrain from using the item (notable exception being Thresh) since usually the coin or dagger are more viable options to compliment their skillset/scaling.

Comment: It's not what he asked, he asked when he should take FoTM, not necessarely whether or not he should buy Targon's brace vs other gold income support items early on.  The issue is between Upgrading Targon / not upgrading targon, and if yes, to FoTM or the Eye

Comment: @Oak Thanks for pointing it out. I think I misunderstood the question a bit. (For me it's kinda obvious to not upgrade it to Eye).

Comment: But that is the point of the question, how gameplay is influenced by what you chose to do with it